# Perfect circled image turning into half an oval shape

Tags: html, css, geometry

If I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<li>
  <a>
    <h2></h2>
    <img>
    <p></p>
    <button></button>
  </a>
</li>
```

And I want the image to be perfectly round, how would I achieve that? I tried using the following after looking at [this article](http://concisecss.com/add-ons/circles/):

```
.circle-box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But using that I get no image at all because of the `height: 0;`, but if I remove that then I get a vertical oval image where only half the image is rounded, like this:

[image: oval image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `border-radius` . But you'll have to set equal height and width of the image and give border-radius only for top and right.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/728/

CSS:

```
img {    
    border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
    height:600px; //sample 
    width:600px; //sample
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/" />
```

In case of unequal width and height of image, you can replace `img` with a `div` and then set the image as the background.

CSS:

```
 div {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
    background-image:url("http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/1/");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/729/

Answer (score 0):

Just give border-radius to 50%. It will do the trick.

```
.circle-box {
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```